# AWS IAM policy issue

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-iam

I created an IAM user named sally and did not attach any managed policy while creating. Then attached the following IAM policy to it.

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Action": "S3:*",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::cat-pics",
                "arn:aws:s3:::cat-pics/*"
            ],
            "Effect": "Allow"
        }
    ]
}
```

But when I log in as sally user into the console, I keep getting the following error:
Error
Access Denied
Basically, the user is not able to see the cat-pics bucket or any objects uploaded to it. What am I missing here? Do I need to add any managed policy to the user? Please let me know.

Thanks

Comment: Are you sure you logged in as the correct user?

Comment: yes I am sure, as I can see sally@account-id in the top right corner of the console. Also bucket exists in the Mumbai region.

Comment: Try this url. https://s3.console.aws.amazon.com/s3/buckets/cat-pics

Answer (score 1):

This is the correct policy document for a user trying to access buckets through console.

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "TheseActionsSupportBucketResourceType",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:ListBucket",
                "s3:ListBucketMultipartUploads",
                "s3:ListBucketVersions"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::cat-pics"
            ]
        },
        {
            "Sid": "TheseActionsRequireAllResources",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:ListAllMyBuckets",
                "s3:ListMultipartUploadParts"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "*"
            ]
        },
        {
            "Sid": "TheseActionsRequireSupportsObjectResourceType",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:GetObject"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::cat-pics/*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Detailed explanation for the issue is provided here:
https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/iam-policy-summaries-now-help-you-identify-errors-and-correct-permissions-in-your-iam-policies/
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that this policy allows full access to *only this bucket*, but if you use the Console you need other permissions to reach that. The [AWS documentation](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/writing-iam-policies-how-to-grant-access-to-an-amazon-s3-bucket/) states that you need the `GetBucketLocation` and the `ListAllMyBuckets` permissions, which are outside of the bucket, to use the console.

Add this to the policy and it should work:

```
{
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": [
        "s3:GetBucketLocation",
        "s3:ListAllMyBuckets"
      ],
      "Resource": "*"
    },
```